# Trabajo en consola con Java

Tags: java

Lo que quiero hacer consiste básicamente en que lo **`anterior impreso en consola se borre`**, osea, que si por ejemplo escribo un programa que imprima un `"Hola mundo"` en la consola, que la siguiente instrucción despumes del `System.out.println("Hola mundo");` 
sea una instrucción que borre lo anterior escrito, que seria en este caso el `hola mundo`.

Comment: Es trabajo escolar? Cuantos puntos de calificación estamos hablando?

Comment: Hablamos de consola en Windows o Linux? si es Windows, una solución es la que dice @HeZu Jared

Comment: Trabajo propio, no se a que te refieres con puntos de calificación, consola de windows, déjame checo

Answer (score 0):

Agrega muchas línea en blanco con un for antes de la nueva instrucción.

`for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
System.out.println("");
}`

Esa puede ser una solución a tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que JAVA no tiene una instrucción para borrar la consola. Puedes imprimir el caracter `backspace` que en unicode es `0008` pero eso solo funciona para la linea actual. Por ejemplo:

```
System.out.println("hola mundo\u0008");
```

Eso solo imprime `hola mund` sin embargo no funciona para las lineas que ya están impresas antes del `\n`. Incluso intentando llamar al clear del shell `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("clear");` no funciona.

Espero que te resulte útil, pero creo que la solución es la que dice @Hezu Jared.